# Storing string in numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I create the following:

```
a=np.eye(2, dtype='S17')
```

But when I print it I get:

```
print(a)
[[b'1' b'']
 [b'' b'1']]
```

Why does it happen and what I can do to just get the strings without b? Or should I change the way of introducing the data or the `dtype`?

The desired output would be:

```
[['1' '']
 ['' '1']]
```

So that I can replace this strings by others

Comment: Why not change your dtype to an int

Comment: Because I want to store strings there, therefore when I create the matrix I first say what type of data I will put inside and then add it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.char.decode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.decode.html#numpy.core.defchararray.decode) to decode the bytes literal:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.eye(2, dtype='S17')                                                                                   

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[b'1', b''],                                                                                                
       [b'', b'1']],                                                                                               
      dtype='|S17')                                                                                                

In [4]: np.char.decode(a, 'ascii')                                                                                 
Out[4]: 
array([['1', ''],                                                                                                  
       ['', '1']],                                                                                                 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Instead of `dtype='S17'` changing it to `'<U1'` produces the same effect thanks!